# How to check number?

Tags: c++

Could anyone please tell me how to check what number I've got from a * b? Which is I would like to know every part of this number so for example if the result from this expression would be 25 I would like to know that first digit is two and second digit is five.

Comment: @drelihan and what if result equals 26?

Comment: for (int k=-2147483648;k<2147483647;k++)
{ if (k==a*b) printf("a*b=%d",k); }

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you... heres the problem with this question. You have asked a rather (some what) simple question regarding c++ on a thursday night (when all of the bitter lonely nerds are usually on) You would be getting better answers if you had asked this in the day time.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat as a matter of fact I've asked this question on friday morning 10:20am ;)

Comment: @Knowing me knowing you: No, you asked it at 11:20am. ;)

Comment: Why do we have so many time zones ? Who cares that the sun rises at 7am or 3pm ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

perhaps a little overkill... but even works with doubles

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double a = 5.2;
    double b = 7;
    double z = a*b;

    std::stringstream s;
    s << z;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.str().length(); i++)
        std::cout << i << ": " << s.str()[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is going to be a `.` somewhere :)

Answer (score 3):

```
a mod 10 == last digit of a
a / 10 == a without its last digit
```

So, for 25:

```
25 % 10 == 5 => 5 is the last digit of 25
25 / 10 == 2
2 % 10 == 2 => 2 is the first digit of 25
```

You can use these in a while loop to get each digit.

```
while (num > 0)
{
    digit = num % 10;
    // digit is now the current digit, counting from the right towards the left.
    num /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the result of the integer division by the appropriate power of ten.

```
int exp = std::floor( std::log10( num ) );
int first_digit = num / int( std::pow( 10.0, exp ) );
```

This is an (inefficient) way to get the first digit directly. It would be better to iterate starting from the last.

Comment: yes that would solve the problem with the unit part but how to get tens and hundreds and so on? I thought maybe some bit shifting would be of help.

Answer (score 2):

```
int val = res;

while( val > 0 )
{
   std::cout << val % 10 << endl; 
   val /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[30];
sprintf(str,"%d",a*b);
int ndigits = strlen(str);
```

There you have all digits of your value in the string, and the number of digits in ndigits.

e.g. if a*b = 25 you get

```
ndigits==2
str[ndigits-1]=='5'
str[ndigits-2]=='2'
```

What do you want this for?

Answer (score 1):

There's probably an underlying misunderstanding here. The result of the multiplication will most likely be `0x00000019`. (Number of leading zeroes will differ). The second step, converting it to canonical decimal will yield `"25"`.

It's important to realize that computers, unlike normal humans, don't do their math in decimal but in binary. Hence, if you want to check a property like "last **decimal** digit of a number", it's not directly available to them.

Answer (score 0):

Just remember, that e.g. 2101 is basically just 2*10^3 + 1*10^2 + 0*10^1 + 1*10^0.

Comment: Wrong. `1234 / 10^2` will give you `12`, not the digit at the second position

Comment: You were very close initially :). You can use `(num / 10^k) % 10` to get the `k` th digit.